Fusion products and states in the fusion spaces of a non-Abelian topological order
I am having some basic confusions about the definitions of the fusion products and the states in the fusion space of a non-Abelian topological order, as described in the paper Microscopic definitions of anyon data by Kawagoe and Levin.
Let me start with some assumptions about the topological order. I assume that the size of the anyon is roughly $d$, the minimally allowed distance between two anyons is $\ell$, and the linear size of the system is $L$. The thermodynamic limit amounts to taking $L\rightarrow\infty$, and I assume that $d$ and $\ell$ are both finite in the thermodynamic limit. Moreover, I assume that $d\ll\ell$.
My first question is: Are the above assumptions about these length scales reasonable?
Below I will describe some other questions related to the fusion products and states in the fusion space.
According to the paragraph above equation (6.2) in the cited paper, if two distinct anyons $c$ and $d$ are both fusion products of anyons $a$ and $b$ with fusion multiplicity 1, then there exist unitary operators $U^{ab}_c$ and $U^{ab}_d$, such that
\begin{equation}
U^{ab}_c|c\rangle=|a, b\rangle,
\quad
U^{ab}_d|d\rangle=|a, b\rangle,
\end{equation}
where $|a, b\rangle$ is a two-anyon state with anyons $a$ and $b$ that are separated by a distance about $\ell$, and $|c\rangle$ and $|d\rangle$ are single-anyon states with anyons $c$ and $d$, respectively.
My second question is: Are the sizes of the supports of $U^{ab}_c$ and $U^{ab}_d$ basically of the order of $\ell$?
My understanding of the discussion above equation (6.2) makes me think that the answer to the second question is "yes". However, if that is indeed the case, then
\begin{equation}
|d\rangle=(U^{ab}_d)^{-1}U^{ab}_c|c\rangle,
\end{equation}
which means that states $|c\rangle$ and $|d\rangle$ can be related to each other by an operator with support of the order $\ell$. I think this violates the basic definition of anyon types, because states $|c\rangle$ and $|d\rangle$ can only be connected by operators with support at least of the order $L$.
Then why is the answer to the second question "no"? From the discussion in another stackexchange post, the issue seems to be that what I wrote as $U^{ab}_{c}$ and $U^{ab}_d$ above are in general not unitary or not even invertible, so $(U^{ab}_{c})^{-1}$ and $(U^{ab}_{d})^{-1}$ do not exist. If this is true, it indeed resolves the above puzzle. But this would mean that the Kawagoe-Levin definition of fusion products is problematic. In particular, they should not demand that $|a, b\rangle$ can be obtained from a single-anyon state by a local unitary operator. Instead, $|a, b\rangle$ can be obtained from $|c\rangle$ via a non-invertible local operator with support that has size $\sim\ell$.
My third question is: Are the operators that connect the fusion products of $a$ and $b$ and the state $|a,b\rangle$ indeed non-invertible, in contrary to the statement by Kawagoe and Levin that they are unitary?
The next question is related to states in the fusion space.
According to the paragraph above equation (6.2), the states in the fusion space of the form $|a, b; c, \mu\rangle$ can be obtained from a single anyon $c$ by a unitary operator supported around $c$. Denote this unitary operator by $U^{ab}_{c,\mu}$, I think this definition of $|a, b; c, \mu\rangle$ means that
\begin{equation}
|a, b; c, \mu\rangle = U^{ab}_{c, \mu}|c\rangle,
\end{equation}
where $|c\rangle$ is the single-anyon state of anyon type $c$.
My fourth question is: Are the sizes of the supports of $U^{ab}_{c, \mu}$ and $U^{ab}_{c, \mu'}$ of the order $\ell$?
If the answer to the above question is "yes", then suppose the operator $O$ in equation (6.2) is taken to be $O=U^{ab}_{c, \mu'}(U^{ab}_{c, \mu})^{-1}$, where $\mu\neq\mu'$, we have
\begin{equation}
\langle a, b; c, \mu'|O|a, b; c, \mu\rangle=1,
\end{equation}
My fifth question is: In equation (6.2), what is the allowed size of the support of the operator $O$? Can this size be $\ell$ or should it be much smaller than $\ell$?
If $U^{ab}_{c; \mu}$ and $U^{ab}_{c; \mu'}$ can indeed be unitary and the size of the operator $O$ is allowed to be as large as $\ell$, the equation (6.2) is violated by taking $O=U^{ab}_{c, \mu'}(U^{ab}_{c, \mu})^{-1}$. There can be two resolutions. The first is to demand that $O$ must have a support with a size much smaller than $\ell$, and the second is to say that $U^{ab}_{c; \mu}$ and $U^{ab}_{c; \mu'}$ must be non-invertible.
My last question is: Is it correct that $U^{ab}_{c; \mu}$ and $U^{ab}_{c; \mu'}$ must be non-invertible?
This last question is independent of the fifth question, and I would like to understand both.

It’s not phrased very clearly, but I think by “local operator” they mean an operator supported near the anyons a and b. Therefore U^{a,b}_{c,mu} would not be considered a “local operator”.

@DominicElse Thank you for the comment! I edited the question and I would really appreciate it if you could provide a more extended answer!

Here is an answer to your question about the size of the operators. First of all, the assumptions about the size of the anyons are reasonable. Take for example the "pure" Toric code--i.e. no external magnetic fields. Then we know that the anyons are purely point like, and are created at the ends of open string operators. We can take those string operators to be of some length $l$ as you defined. Now let's say we are not in the pure toric code state. We can still define "thickened" open string operators through slowly turning on the magnetic fields. These thickened string operators will still have support proportional to $l$ but will have another dimension to them, which dictate the size of the anyons. But at the end of the day, we still have finite size anyons and string operators. This procedure is done in this paper by Hastings and Wen. The fact that the size of the supports is controlled comes down to Lieb-Robinson bounds.
The short answer is that the fact there exists a state in the same phase of your system that satisfies your assumptions about the size of the different operators you care about, Lieb-Robinson bounds gaurantee the assumptions will stay true.
